# .NET Core Web Application not finding Assembly Reference

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core

I have added a new ASP.NET Core 2.1 Application project to my existing .NET Solution.  I am targeting .NET Framework with it.  If I check the Properties on the new .NET Core Web App project that has been added I can see it is targeting Framework 4.7.2.

I have made sure the Service Layer project I want to reference is also on Framework version 4.7.2.  I then right click on the Core Web Application and Add reference to the Service Layer project and it seems to have added.

However when I attempt to use the reference I get the type or namespace does not exist error are you missing an assembly reference

Under Dependencies I can see it has added a projects icon and then my Service Layer reference is there but when I double click it I get the error below:

[image]

I also check the csproj file of the ASP.NET Core Web App and I see the below added.

```
<ItemGroup>

    <ProjectReference Include="..\CarWarehouse.Service\Service.CarWarehouse.csproj" />

  </ItemGroup>
```

Am I missing something in adding this reference correctly?

Comment: Have you installed dotnet core 2.1? https://www.microsoft.com/net/download/dotnet-core/2.1

Comment: @Monofuse - I'm running VS 2017 with latest updates installed so 15.9 (which looks like it should have the SDK Included as part of that)